# How to add username in urls with OneToOne field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I have model and serializer and i want api to use username not pk

How can i do that? I actually tried to use lookup field but thats not rly working

models.py

```
class IndividualUser(models.Model):
    individual_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_("first name"), max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=150)
```

urls.py

```
path('api/profile/<str:individual_user>/', IndividualClientDetailApiView.as_view()),
```

views.py

```
class IndividualClientDetailApiView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = IndividualUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IndividualClientSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrAdminOrReadOnly)

    lookup_field = 'individual_user'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
class IndividualClientDetailApiView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = IndividualUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IndividualClientSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrAdminOrReadOnly)

    lookup_field = 'individual_user__username'
    lookup_url_kwarg = "individual_user"
```

Here, by pointing `lookup_field` to username of the `User` model, the queryset will look up in that field when a request is made, while passing the value of `indivisual_user`’s username from the url (via `lookup_url_kwarg`). Thus the url will look like this:

> localhost:8000/api/profile/myusername/

More information can be found in [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes).

Comment: I got an error ```Expected view IndividualClientDetailApiView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "'individual_user". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.```

Comment: its a typo i made. it should be individual_user

Comment: Yeah i know i fixed that but i guess its some my problems ill try to fix that and ill give you feedback